# Jquery - hover event disappears after mousedown event is triggered.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have an issue with a jquery script.  Page loads with the script below.  The hover event works fine.  However, if the mousedown event fires, the hover event functionality subsequently disappears and I don't get any rollovers.  Any ideas as to why and how to keep the hover event firing off each and every time?  Viewing the page in IE.

```
// Rollover effect for sign.
$("#sign").hover(function () {
    $("#sign").css('background', 'url(img/default/signinon.png) no-repeat 0 0');
},
function () {
    $("#sign").css('background', 'url(img/default/signin.png) no-repeat 0 0');
});


//Mousedown function... 
$(document).mousedown(function (event) {

    var $target = $(event.target);


    // A click outside of the sign in panel or a click on the sign in button when the body panel is visible, hides the display.

    if ((!$target.is('#sign') && !$target.is('#sign-in-panel') && !$target.parents().is('#sign-in-panel') && !$target.parents().is('#sign')) ||
   ($target.is('#sign') && $("#sign-in-panel").css('visibility') == 'visible')) {
        $("#sign-in-panel").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $("#sign").css('background', 'url(img/default/signin.png) no-repeat 0 0');

    }
    else {
        // Show the panel
        $("#sign-in-panel").css('visibility', 'visible');

    }
});
```

Comment: Why not use click() instead of mousedown()?

Comment: click() in lieu of mousedown() appears to yield the same result.  Once the initial click is done, the hover event doesn't fire.

Comment: Works here for me:http://jsfiddle.net/8FFDF/ try putting your code there

Comment: Thanks.  I think the issue occurs only when the css background property is changed to a new image.  The source that you have on jsfiddle doesn't reset the background.  I noticed that this line:    $("#sign").css('background', 'url(img/default/signin.png) no-repeat 0 0'); in the mousedown event disabled the hover event after it executed--or at least that's what I'm seeing currently.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion try changing the background from css not jquery

```
.signinClass
{
background :url(img/default/signin.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.signinClass:hover
{
background :url(img/default/signinon.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Mouse down might be preventing hover event from triggering.

Comment: I can do that, but I was hoping to use jquery to control the whole thing.  There isn't a way to reset the hover event?

Comment: you could toggle the class of that particular element if that's what you mean by resetting the  hover event.